# How to ignore java.time package in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsr310, threetenbp

I am currently working on an Android Studio project with a minimum API version of 17 (JellyBean), so I cannot use the `java.time` package. Instead, I am using the ThreeTen backport for Android (`com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0`).

My problem is that every class in `com.threeten.bp` matches one in `java.time`, and I find that it is *very* easy to accidentally import the wrong class, since the auto-complete popup shows the `java.time` option first. I need a way to just remove that `java.time` package from my project, or at least tell Android Studio to ignore it. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You cannot remove it from the project, other than by setting a low enough `compileSdkVersion`, from before `java.time` was added. That won't work very well for the rest of your app, though. I don't know if there is a way to tailor auto-complete to filter out certain packages, though that sounds like a nice feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable auto-import classes of this package. Add `java.time` into:

```
Editor--> General --> Auto import --> exclude from import and completion
```